# PostgreSQL - jsonb index is not being applied

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, jsonb, b-tree

I have a table called **users** that contains over 2 millions records with the following structure:

```
create table users { 
   id integer not null,
   langs jsonb
}
```

The column **langs** contains the following data in rows:

```
    {"default_lang": "en", "custom_langs": ["en", "de"]}
    {"default_lang": "fr", "custom_langs": ["en", "de"]}
    {"default_lang": "pt", "custom_langs": ["en", "de", "fr"]}
```

The idea is to select only rows whose **default_lang** is not contained in **custom_langs**. So, I am able to achieve it like so:

```
SELECT id, langs
FROM  users
WHERE deleted=false and (langs->'default_lang' <@ (langs->'custom_langs') = false)
```

I have also created the following index:

```
    CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS users_langs ON users 
    USING btree ((langs->'default_lang'), (langs->'custom_langs'))
    where langs->'default_lang' <@ (langs->'custom_langs') = false;
```

But the index users_langs is not being applied. Any ideas on how to fix this. thanks in advance.

Here the query plan result:

```
 HashAggregate  (cost=957627.32..1002810.29 rows=2536588 width=8) (actual time=17095.651..17096.210 rows=2233 loops=1)
   Output: id
   Group Key: users.id
   Planned Partitions: 64  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 913kB
   Buffers: shared hit=47315 read=762287
   I/O Timings: read=11079.509
   ->  Seq Scan on public.users  (cost=0.00..821285.71 rows=2536588 width=8) (actual time=17.969..17086.833 rows=2233 loops=1)
         Output: id
         Filter: ((NOT users.deleted) AND (NOT ((users.langs -> 'default_langs'::text) <@ (users.langs -> 'custom_langs'::text))))
         Rows Removed by Filter: 2774667
         Buffers: shared hit=47315 read=762287
         I/O Timings: read=11079.509
 Settings: effective_cache_size = '8041608kB', jit = 'off'
 Query Identifier: -9027923201169468774
 Planning:
   Buffers: shared hit=427 read=32
   I/O Timings: read=4.276
 Planning Time: 5.737 ms
 Execution Time: 17096.749 ms
```

Comment: Could you please share the result from `explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings)` for your SQL statement? (in plain text, as an update of your question). And how many records does this table have? Just 3? And what is the relation between `users` and `languages`? Your query doesn't use the table `languages`.

Comment: The table users is big with over 2 millions records.

Comment: It seems `deleted=false` portion of the table is much bigger than `langs->'default_lang' <@ (langs->'custom_langs') = false`, so you may want to add `deleted=false` to your indexes filter condition.

Comment: Did you try a GIN index? `CREATE INDEX idx_users_langs_not_deleted ON public.users USING gin (langs) WHERE deleted = false;` You should most likely also set a lower value to random_page_cost, something much closer to 1 than the default value 4.

Comment: Yes, I tried and still not working.

Comment: Your current setting for random_page_cost is most likely not correct. Besides that, json could be the problem here: expected number of records 2536588, in reality just 2233. That means the statistics are way off. You could try some custom statistics: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createstatistics.html

Comment: Works for me.  What version are you using?

Comment: @jjanes I'm using PostgreSQL 14.7.

Comment: The query you show cannot give rise to a hashagg.  What is your real query?

Answer (score 1):

The partial index is usable, and will be used if you disable seq scans (`set enable_seqscan=off`), but it won't be used normally just because it is believed to be slower than the full table scan would, because the row estimates are so wrong.

Unfortunately, I can't see how to get the estimates correct, not even by using custom statistics on the expression.  I don't know why the custom statistics don't work. You could use the 3rd party extension pg_hint_plan to force an index scan.

After playing with this a bit more, the problem is the `= false`.  The partial index code knows how to deal with that, but apparently the custom statistics code does not.  If you create the stats and analyze the table:

```
create statistics lsdkfj on (langs->'default_lang' <@ (langs->'custom_langs')) 
from users;
analyze users;
```

then the stats will be right but only if the query is written with `is false` not `= false`.  Then an index will be used (but only if it too is changed to `is false`).